# Pyspark - remove duplicates from dataframe keeping the last appearance

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to dedupe a spark dataframe leaving only the latest appearance.
The duplication is in three variables:

```
NAME
ID
DOB
```

I succeeded in Pandas with the following:

```
df_dedupe = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['NAME','ID','DOB'], keep='last', inplace=False)
```

But in spark I tried the following:

```
df_dedupe = df.dropDuplicates(['NAME', 'ID', 'DOB'], keep='last')
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: dropDuplicates() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keep'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://quynhcodes.wordpress.com/2016/07/29/drop-duplicates-by-some-condition/

Comment: Base on the [document][1] `dropDuplicates` do not have para `keep` in `pyspark`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help.
I followed your directives but the outcome was not as expected:

```
d1 = [('Bob', '10', '1542189668', '0', '0'),  ('Alice', '10', '1425298030', '154', '39'), ('Bob', '10', '1542189668', '178', '42')]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['NAME', 'ID', 'DOB' , 'Height' , 'ShoeSize'])
df_dedupe = df1.dropDuplicates(['NAME', 'ID', 'DOB'])
df_reverse = df1.sort((["NAME", "ID", "DOB"]), ascending= False)
df_dedupe.join(df_reverse,['NAME','ID','DOB'],'inner')
df_dedupe.show(100, False)
```

The outcome was:

```
+-----+---+----------+------+--------+    
|NAME |ID |DOB       |Height|ShoeSize|
+-----+---+----------+------+--------+
|Bob  |10 |1542189668|0     |0       |
|Alice|10 |1425298030|154   |39      |
+-----+---+----------+------+--------+
```

Showing the "Bob" with corrupted data.

Finally, I changed my approach and converted the DF to Pandas and then back to spark:

```
p_schema = StructType([StructField('NAME',StringType(),True),StructField('ID',StringType(),True),StructField('DOB',StringType(),True),StructField('Height',StringType(),True),StructField('ShoeSize',StringType(),True)])
d1 = [('Bob', '10', '1542189668', '0', '0'),  ('Alice', '10', '1425298030', '154', '39'), ('Bob', '10', '1542189668', '178', '42')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d1, p_schema)
pdf = df.toPandas()
df_dedupe = pdf.drop_duplicates(subset=['NAME','ID','DOB'], keep='last', inplace=False)

df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_dedupe, p_schema)
df_spark.show(100, False)
```

This finally brought the correct "Bob":

```
+-----+---+----------+------+--------+
|NAME |ID |DOB       |Height|ShoeSize|
+-----+---+----------+------+--------+
|Alice|10 |1425298030|154   |39      |
|Bob  |10 |1542189668|178   |42      |
+-----+---+----------+------+--------+
```

Of course, I'd still like to have a purely Spark solution but the lack of indexing seems to be problematic with Spark.

Thanks!

Comment: I have to thank you a lot for your code, it helped me so much !
I did a function to do the AddOrUpdate the exact way you're doing it, and it works !
If anybody want me to share it, please don't hesitate to ask

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html the documentation of the function `dropDuplicates(subset=None)`, it only allows a **subset** as parameter. Why would you like to keep the last, if they're all equal?

**EDIT**

As @W-B pointed, u want the other columns. My solution will be to sort the original dataframe in reverse order, and use the `df_dedupe` on the three repeated columns to make an inner join and only preserve the last values.

```
df_dedupe.join(original_df,['NAME','ID','DOB'],'inner')
```

Comment: Cause there still other column , he need the last value for them